# SQL: Oracle - Parameters in query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to use the `vs2008` query builder to create a query with a `parameter`.
I know that in `sql server` it would work with:

```
select col1,col2
from tbl
where col3=@myParam
```

How would it be typed in oracle or is it `pl/sql`?
I get the problem in the `@myParam` part.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Oracle `SQL parameters` are specified using `:`

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM tbl WHERE col3=:myParam
```

You will have to be careful when specifying this as an `OracleParameter` though, as some libraries miss off the `:`, and some require it to bind correctly.

Comment: when i do that, it accepts the query, but when i prevew the query it says: "ORA-01008: not all variables bound" and i did put a value in that parameter for the preview.

Comment: The problem is that i use an old version of oracle (7) and it does not support named parameters.

Comment: @thecoop: *bind* variables are prefixed with a colon.