# SQL Aggregating data based on condition containing the key fields for aggregation

Tags: sql, oracle, conditional-statements, aggregation

I am new to SQL (Oracle SQL if it makes a difference) but it so happens I have to use it. I need to aggregate data by some key fields (CustId, AppId). I also have some AppDate, PDate and Amount.[Initial data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9z8qo.png)
What I need to do is aggregate but for each key field combination I need to aggregate the data from other rows with the following conditions:

- CustID = CustID aka take only information for this custID
- AppId != AppId aka take only information for application different than the current one.
- AppDate >= PDate aka take only information available at time of application

From a quick look at SQL language my approach was the use of:

```
select CustId, AppId, Sum(case when 
custid=custid and Appid!=Appid and AppDate >= PDate then Amount else 0 end) as SumAmount
From Table 
Group by CustId AppId
```

Unfortunately, the result I get are all 0 for SumAmount. My guess it is because of the last 2 conditions.
The results I want to get from the example table are: [Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXkW4.png)
Also, I would probably add condition that AppDate - AppDate of other AppID > 6months exclude those from the aggregated amounts.

P.S. I am really sorry for the substandard formatting and probably bad code. I am not really experienced on how to do it.

Edit: I've found a solution as follows:

```
select distinct a.CustId, a.AppId, a.AppDate, b.PDate, b.Amount
from table a
inner join (select CustId, AppId, Amount, PDate from Table) b
on a.CustId = b.CustId and a.AppId != b.AppId
where a.AppDate >= b.PDate
```

After that I aggregate by AppId summing the amount.
Basically, I just append the same information based on a condition and since I get a lot of full duplicates I deduplicate with distinct.

Comment: At first glance `custid=custid` looks as if it will probably always be True and `Appid!=Appid` always False, are you looking for `parameterized queries`? And the `Group by CustId AppId` looks as if it would work better with a comma `,` between the two column names

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086480/sql-oracle-parameters-in-query

Comment: I am not sure what parameterized queries are. I will look into the link you sent. Now I will know what to look for.

Comment: They are the tool for better type casting between `RDBMS` server and client, and for preventing the infamous `SQL Injection` attacks. I'd suggest doing web searches for those terms

Comment: Note that I am new to SQL and this was my approach. My question is on how to create such a query with the mentioned conditions. My problem stems from the need for every AppId to look only at the other AppId from the same customer and filter them before aggregation. I imagine the filter is the case when conditions. I just do not know how to look in certain other AppIds because the group by basically just takes the records of the current CustId and AppId from what I gather. Maybe I need to just derive a field which has the condition mentioned above without aggregating.

Comment: Okay, I am old to SQL but did not understand yet what your problem is :) What I do know is that even experienced developers' SQL questions work best not by doing narrative descriptions but  by showing a few sample data rows via few `Create Table ...` and `Insert Into ...` SQL code lines, and then show the expected result. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question

Comment: I've added screenshots of what I have and what results I expect in the answer if this could be a guide to what is expected.

Comment: SQL or not, this is one of the worst posts I've seen in SO. forget about the code and put some effort explaining the transformation logic between the data sample and the required results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution as follows:

```
select distinct a.CustId, a.AppId, a.AppDate, b.PDate, b.Amount
from table a
inner join (select CustId, AppId, Amount, PDate from Table) b
on a.CustId = b.CustId and a.AppId != b.AppId
where a.AppDate >= b.PDate
```

After that I aggregate by AppId summing the amount.
Basically, I just append the same information based on a condition and since I get a lot of full duplicates I deduplicate with distinct.